# Odd Behavior with Quarkus Kubernetes Config Extension and Overriding application.yml

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, quarkus

We just started seeing an odd behavior using the Quarkus Kubernetes Config Extension and overriding properties in the application.yml

We have started to use configmap environment variables to override application.yml properties like this:

```
QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL: "https://sso.localhost/auth/realms/test"
```

The expectation is that it overrides any setting in the application.yml and takes precedence but it did not.

Instead we did this in the application.yml and it works.

```
quarkus:
  oidc:
    auth-server-url: ${QUARKUS_OIDC_AUTH_SERVER_URL:https://localhost:8543/auth/realms/test}
```

We are seeing this across any environment variable in the configmap that is meant to override an existing application.yml property. Outside of a native build, in our CI for example, we use this same tactic to override properties and it works.

Another test we tried was to directly change the `QUARKUS_LOG_LEVEL` to something bad.  This showed no changes after the pod depending on the config was restarted.  Doing the same to a property that depended on an environment variable ( ${MY_LOG_LEVEL:debug} ) broke as expected.

Have there been any changes recently that would/should affect the precedence of the properties when using the Quarkus Kubernetes Config extension?

Comment: if you got a reproducer where it worked in past but does not now please open issue with reproducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being my own fault and pure luck it had works as it did before (because I was mostly defining each property in the profiles).

I was able to leverage the new profile.parent to build of a hiearchy of profiles much cleaner and realized (at least it seems that way) that the kubernetes config extension only deals with the application properties not setting environment variables so, once I included those as configmaps and secrets in my kubernetes configuration everything worked as expected.

```
kubernetes:
  env:
    configmaps:
       - my-configmap
    secrets:
       - my-secrets
kubernetes-config:
  config-maps:
    - my-configmap
    - my-service
  secrets:
    ~:
      - my-secrets
```